# How to tell a GUI to render the correct control for a plug in setting?

Tags: .net, wpf, user-interface, plugins

I'm trying to create a plug in style application, but I'm not clear on this part.  Each plug in has it's own settings class that is used to communicate with the GUI (get and put configurable settings in the form of simple key value pairs)

But say one of the properties in the actual plug in is like a collection with 3 possible choices representing an Enum or a List of objects.

How am I supposed to tell the GUI that "This property of the plug in is currently configured by default as 'CHOICE 1' (via a string in the settings class).  But it is also capable of being set to 'CHOICE 2' and 'CHOICE 3'"

Is this something can be done automatically so that the plug in itself alerts the host application that there are three possibilities thereby implying to use a drop down control (or similar) to list all three choices?  Or is it something 'me' as the programmer of the GUI is supposed to be told by the author of the plug in - that this particular property should display as a drop down with these three choices?

**EDIT:  I guess my main question would be how would the host application know about the other choices available for a particular property when all it sees is a single string value via a settings class?**

Answer (score 1):

I would think the plug-in should "draw" itself. It makes no sense for the host application to know how to draw every possible plug-in.

Comment: Well the core of my application is a class library and the plug ins belong to the class library.  The host application is going to be WPF but I was wondering if I want to keep the class library in the dark without knowledge of the host type (i.e. WPF or WinForms or Windows Store)  is that something that is even possible?  What do you do if you want to later use the library with a GUI host other than WPF?  (Not that I'm going to, but just curious what to do in that case)

Comment: Every plugin system I've seen and written works where the host app exposes a IPlugIn type interface that the plug-ins implement. The interface might have "Init()", "Cleanup()", "GetPlugInInfo()" etc. as well as expose events to notify the host. If there is UI or something, the interface should have a "UserControl GetConfigControl()" type getter and the host app would host the control. You shouldn't return the definition of a control, but rather a control.

Answer (score 0):

If you are responsible also for the host application, it should publish some `interface`s. The host itself do not know the implementation, which is *in the dark*, but do know how to respond in accordance with the `interfaces`.